# Unable to Set WPF's ComboBox Item Text Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, itemssource

I have done a lot of reading on this subject and I am getting more and more frustrated and confused that a simple thing like this is so difficult to do in the absence of MVVM.

I am setting up the list as:

```
cboLender.ItemsSource = lenders;
```

The source list is custom typed list containing `Lender` objects. With properties on it like: `ID` and `CompanyName`.

Then to programmatically set it like:

```
        var selectedLender = lenders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == _someId);
        cboLender.SelectedItem = selectedLender;
        cboLender.SelectedValuePath = "CompanyName";
        cboLender.SelectedValue = selectedLender.CompanyName;
        //cboLender.DisplayMemberPath = "CompanyName";
```

In code the item is **set** correctly to become the `SelectedItem`, but on the UI the combo box is empty. So it looks like ***nothing*** has been selected. I tried the display member path property also but that does not work either.

This is such a simple problem but I have been trying and researching for ours now and now I need help.

Comment: did you set DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: I did - could do with a fleshed out example to understand this problem better - updated the question.

Comment: Tried your example on my side and everything worked fine. Where did you put your code that select the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 LenderList = new ObservableCollection<Lender>();
            Lender l = new Lender();
            l.CompanyName = "11212dffdd";
            l.ID = "1";
            LenderList.Add(l);
            cboLender.ItemsSource = LenderList;
            cboLender.DisplayMemberPath = "CompanyName";


            var selectedLender = LenderList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == "1");
            cboLender.SelectedItem = selectedLender;
            cboLender.SelectedValuePath = "CompanyName";
            cboLender.SelectedValue = selectedLender.CompanyName;
```

in Code behind

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Inotify
        /// <summary>
        /// Property Change Event
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Property Change Method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="prop">Property Name</param>
        internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        private ObservableCollection<Lender> lenderList;

        public ObservableCollection<Lender> LenderList
        {
            get { return lenderList; }
            set
            {
                lenderList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("LenderList");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LenderList = new ObservableCollection<Lender>();
            Lender l = new Lender();
            l.CompanyName = "11212dffdd";
            l.ID = "1";
            LenderList.Add(l);
            cboLender.ItemsSource = LenderList;
            cboLender.DisplayMemberPath = "CompanyName";


            var selectedLender = LenderList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == "1");
            cboLender.SelectedItem = selectedLender;
            cboLender.SelectedValuePath = "CompanyName";
            cboLender.SelectedValue = selectedLender.CompanyName;

        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class Lender : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Inotify
        /// <summary>
        /// Property Change Event
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Property Change Method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="prop">Property Name</param>
        internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private string companyName;

        public string CompanyName
        {
            get { return companyName; }
            set
            {
                companyName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CompanyName");
            }
        }

        private string id;

        public string ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Window1" x:Name="testWindow" Height="500" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Width="300" >
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel x:Name="stk">
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboLender" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have spotted some binding errors in the Output window. Possibly a xaml related binding expression error. BRB

Comment: I had some binding errors in xaml that were creating problems for me and were preventing the UI from updating correctly. Thanks for the steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the *SelectedIndex* of the *ComboBox* to 0. The default value is -1.

Comment: Please be careful when editing other posts. XAML should not be formatted as code snippet, because it can't be executed on the SO page.